# .bat Inserting text in Every line in a notepad without repeating typing Set /p line1= and echo text %line1%>output.txt can it be done

Tags: batch-file

No need to find a text word just simply adding a text in every single line of paragraph
can it be done

Save it as Setline or Anything

```
ECHO OFF
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (Originalfilename.txt) do echo(Set /p line%%i=)>Setline.txt  
exit
```

Save it as Echoline or anything

```
 ECHO OFF
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (Originalfilename.txt) do echo(echo Insertext %%line%%i%%^>^>FinalOutput.txt)>Echoline.txt
exit
```

Note: 
I named Orginalfilename as Numbers.txt since its what ill be using for line numbers

OriginalFilename - Must Not contain Space or Else it Wont Work
So Better Rename The File It Happens to me since im a newbee
And End up Wondering Whats Wrong hehehehe

Sorry but this did not work
(for /l %%i in (1,1,500) do echo %%i)>fileofnumber.txt

```
Output You'll get here is
Path of where its been save then
1
Path of where its been save then
2
```

since what i wanted to do is

```
1
2
3
and so on
```

heres a Working one that i found its in vbscript by Keebellah on textmechanic

Save it as AnyFilename.vbs - you copy and paste the code on notepad 
once done Double click it and it will generate the numbers 
It would be save on your Desktop

```
Public Const cHideWindow = 0, cNormalWindow = 1
Set WSHShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")       
Set FSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set EnvVar = wshShell.Environment("Process")
tBestand= EnvVar("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Numbers.txt"
Set Bestand = fso.createtextfile(tBestand,1)
t = 0
For x = 1 To 10000
Bestand.WriteLine(Right("00000000" & x,8))
Next
Bestand.close
WScript.quit
```

Note:
Copy the generated Number.txt to the same Folder of
Echoline.bat and Setline.bat or whatever you named it

Then The Part what i wanted to do 
Save it as Output or anything

```
ECHO OFF
(
Set /p line1=
```

Paste the generated Set line Here

```
)<OriginalFilename
echo inserttext %line1%>FinalOutPut.txt
```

Paste the generated Echoline Here

```
exit
```

Yeah Now I Dont have A Problem on ; and Space being omitted Thank Goodness Theres no Special Character 
on what im working on only pure text and ;  :  '  -  (  )

This is still incomplete though After Experimenting on it 
you'll end up with nothing if you encounter
%  ^  &  <  >  |  "

is there a way to improve it further where once you encounter
%  ^  &  <  >  |  " it will just echo %  ^  &  <  >  |  " normally
well you can use single ^% ^& and so on 
but the down side is you'll need to find from the originalfilename and insert ^ one by one
on things like %  ^  &  <  >  |  " not to good if you have a 1000 and more of it

Thanks For the Help Magoo do you think you could still improve it 
well either way i end up finishing with just click and copy on what im supposed to
be doing in 3-4days

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (originalfilename.txt) do echo(inserttext        %%i)>output.txt
```

As a batch line should create a new file `output.txt` by prefixing each non-empty line of `originalfilename.txt` with the string `"inserttext        "`

(Lines beginning <kbd>;</kbd> will be skipped...)

Comment: is it posible to reverse the output ex: 1 inserttext @Magoo

Comment: @Magoo - Why don't you give it a try yourself? You could very quickly answer your own follow up question :-)

Comment: @user3051106 : you could use `...do echo(inserttext %%i somethingelse)>output.txt` if you like - the literal text will be reproduced exactly as typed; the `%%i` will be replaced by the contents of the line as read from the file.

Comment: @Magoo How About Generating a List of Sequential Numbers save it as Text

Comment: One-liner. `(for /l %%i in (1,1,500) do echo %%i)>fileofnumber.txt` - appears to be unrelated to the current question. Questions aren't expensive or rationed on SO.

Comment: @Magoo you'll now why i asked number generator once you see what i edited but do you think you could still improve it. And oh the output im receiving from the code that you gave is path of file and then the number well anyway i already found a solution there is only a trouble on on special symbols like %^&<>|" on the one that i created it would be nice if you could still improve it though well in my case it doesnt bother since i dont found those symbols but it would be nice if theres a solution for it might become handy in the near future